# Add a field to existing vector

Tags: java, file-io, vector

I have a standard program with a list of interview questions that people use when interviewing new members.  The questions are hard coded, the interviewer records the answer to the questions.  The answers when submitted are added to an object (called iQuestions) and then stored in a .txt file on the server.  Well times change and now we want to add additional questions to the list, which is easy enough to do, however when I change the iQuestions in both the server and client, the old records bomb out with a "serialized object" error (the object saved is not the same as the object in the program that I am trying to get from.  What is the easiest way to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

This is where not having the static serialVersionUID defined in a Serializable class can burn you later.  As you state, your new version of the serializable class is different than the one that was used to save off data and as such the "automatic" deserialization cannot determine how to read the data back in to your new version of the class ( http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45 ).  If you still have access to the original iQuestions class, you might consider writing a converter that deserializes the questions using the original class and then write out the relevant data into another format (perhaps using a database to store the questions would be more reliable and easier to update or storing as JSON in a text file for simplicity?).

Comment: so if I declare a serialVersionUID 1234567 with fields ABC, later come around and add D to the object but keep the serialVersionUID 1234567, then I should be able to access fields of the stored object that just has ABC as well as the version of the object that has ABCD?
edit: I do not have access to mySQL and do not have any experience with using it inside Java or any experience using JSON objects so i would rather not use those options.